# GoogleMaps API working only when dev tools is open

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Hey I am trying to have a map in my project. I got my API_KEY from google for GoogleMaps... I have no error in console but map doesnt display anything, till I open developers tools on google Chrome...

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQs6I.png)

After that is working but marker is in work palce.. Still no errors in console.

[image]

WHat am I doing wrong?

Style:

```
#map {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: grey;
}
```

Code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
 <script>
   function initMap() {
   var myLatLng = {lat: -0.250608, lng: 52.025528};

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 4,
   center: myLatLng
   });

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Title!'
    });
  }
 </script>
 <script async defer
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap">
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are init-ing the map in a container that is not visible/has no dimensions.

Opening dev tools triggers a resize on your browser which causes the map to resize itself.**

You can fix it by either:

either waiting to init the map until it's container is visible

or calling `google.maps.event.trigger('resize',map)` (where `map` is an
    instance of the map) when your container becomes visible.

** Proof that this is what's happening: undock your dev tools so it's a floating window. Then refresh your page (with dev tools closed) and open dev tools again after you fail to see the map, it still won't be visible because your browser never resized (because your dev tools is floating and not docked)

Comment: Yes Adam you right... I just have to figure out now how to use google.maps.event.trigger('resize',map) ... Cheers

Comment: @Maria - When the user clicks on the contact us tab - you probably add/remove classes on DOM elements to show the correct tab. Just call the `google.maps.event.trigger('resize',map)` right after you add/remove the DOM classes. Also, declare `var map;` outside your `initMap` function

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure to register your URL / domain with Google for the use of the Maps API? https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/clientside/auth#register-urls

Comment: No thats something i dont even know I had to... I am working locally for now is that a problem?

Comment: Not 100% sure, you say it is showing only when you open Dev Tools? If it is an auth issue with your API Key, take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/troubleshooting-auth

Comment: Yes is working when I open dev tools, but i take a look if is an authentication problem